# Access winform variable from browsercontrol

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I have an application in ASP.Net Ajax. I want to open it via a browsercontrol from a winform, and I wish to access a variable (username) that the user used to log in to the webform with. On load I would like to read that username and perform the rest of my webpage code on that browsercontrol using that username.

My ASP.Net Ajax has been published to a internal web server and the browsercontrol loads that IP address.

Is there any way to achieve this at all?

EDIT:

I have discovered the javascript extension:   window.external
And I can call a C# procedure from the webpage using javascript with it, which is a start, but I need to retrieve a varaible from c# - this is where the problem comes in. I have tried the

```
var name = function window.external.GetGlobalVariable(MyGlobalProcedure, "Cannot Get Value");
```

But javascript error says the method cannot be applied to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer should be as follows:

```
  Public Class Form1

  Dim GlobalVar As String = "Your Name"
  Dim YourBrowser As New WebBrowser

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    YourBrowser.Url = New Uri("Your URL address")
    AddHandler YourBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf PageLoadComplete
  End Sub

  'The invokescript will only work once the HTML has finished loading itself into your WebBrowser
  Sub PageLoadComplete()
    'Must declare the string inside an array as the invokescript only allows an object to be sent
    Dim VarToSend As String() = {GlobalVar}
    YourBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("yourJavascriptfunction", VarToSend)
  End Sub
```

The javascript section should look as follows:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">         
     function userNameSet(name) {                                   
         $(document).ready(function() { 
            //variable now exists inside your WebBrowser client and can be used accordingly now
            alert(name);
         });
     }
  </script>
```

References for answer: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=194

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

"Store that name in a session variable and access the session in your ajax call"

Comment: I have edited the question - Need to access the windows form from the asp, not a webform

Answer (score 0):

In your ASP.Net application create a hidden field (or if it's somewhere on the UI in some control that works also).  Put the username or whatever information you want to share into that field.

From your WinForms program you can request that field through the WebBrowser control like this:

```
   MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtUsername").GetAttribute("value"))
```

The above assumes you have some HTML element called txtUsername with the value attribute set.

Comment: Actually need it the other way around...inside the web application I need to access the variable inside the vb windows form which has the browser control on it